# how can I resize an image ONLY HORIZONTALLY using CSS

Tags: html, css

so I tried to make a small project that is a simple website and I want to resize my image horizontally only. so it would make it fit the page from left to right with the same height as normal. but when I tried to use `width` property in CSS and setting it to 100% it didn't make my image longer but instead bigger.

```css
.wide-pic{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img class="wide-pic" src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/mountain.jpg">
```

Comment: I would increase the width and decrease the height, you should obtain the same effect: `width: 150%; height:50%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with the background-size inside the style.

```css
#example1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/mountain.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>background-size: 100% 50%:</h2>
<div id="example1">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>The size of the background image is set in percent of the parent element; 100% width and 50% height.</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: okay now it worked just have to edit it a lil bit so it have the style that I want. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

you can give it a static height and width.

```
.wide-pic {
   width: 100px; 
   height: 100px; 
}
```

you might want to add object-fit:cover;

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
.wide-pic{
   width: 100%; //give your size
   hight:100%; //give your size
   max-width:100%;
}
```